# Modo correcto para interactuar entre ViewModels MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Estoy construyendo una aplicación WPF con el patrón de diseño MVVM.

Estoy utilizando DataTemplates para cargar controles de usuario dentro de un ContentControl:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type menu:MenuViewModel}">
   <menu:MenuView/>
</DataTemplate>


<ContentControl Content="{Binding Menu}" Visibility="{Binding MenuVisibility, 
        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"/>
```

Además del menú tengo un control de usuario para manejar la StatusBar y aquí es donde me surge la duda. Para que los demás ViewModels puedan interactuar con la StatusBar, lo que he hecho es crear un MainViewModel en cada ViewModel que necesite esta funcionalidad y luego lo asigno desde el MainViewModel así:

```
_ChatViewModel.mainViewModel = this;
CurrentViewModel = _ChatViewModel;
```

Esto funciona, pero creo que debe existir una "rueda" inventada y que me estoy complicando. ¿Existe algún modo más "sencillo", "estándar" que esté pasando por alto?

Comment: usas alguna libreria para implementar MVVM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comunicar viewmodel deberias usar eventos, podrias aplicar el patron `Publish/Subscribe`.

El `MainViewModel` expone un eventos (en tu caso para actualizar el statusbar), y quienes quieran informar de un cambio simplemente lanza el mismo evento respectando la firma y enviando lo argumentos.

De esta forma desacoplas la comunicación.

[Communication Between Views in MVVM (Pub-Sub Pattern)](http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/07/pub-sub-observer-pattern-in-mvvm.html#.Vrj10tAvGUk)

Si aplicas alguna librería estas incluyen este concepto como ser el `MVVM Light’s Messenger` or `Microsoft Prism’s EventAggregator`.

[Communication between ViewModels with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/)

Comment: Gracias por mostrarme la "rueda".